Script works but I get this "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again." message every time
WARNING: I HAVE 0 PROGRAMMING KNOWLEDGE
Hi! I need some help, because I have 0 programming knowledge, and am just trying to run a simple script to generate a list of folders (1st level is fine) of everything that I have in my Google Drive's My Drive. The script must be able to return the owner name (I know technically this should be me, but it's been useful to have this every time), URL link of the folder, and of course folder name.
I just generated a script from Copilot which works perfectly fine, the issue is when I try to open it in a web app that I get the "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again." message. I always make it as far as the HTML page coming up with the one and only button being "Generate Folder List" before getting this message.
I want to use a web app because I plan to share this with the company (we're very small if it helps?), and we have loads of people who will not be able to run the script on their own. Maybe if this doesn't work, I can just do a session with everyone and we run it manually together, but ideally, I would just like for them to click the URL, click the "Generate list of folders" button, and get the data we need from each person. If this is the only route i could take, or if there's anything else I should try, then please fire away!
Below is the script that I used:
function doGet() {
  // This function is required for web app deployment.
  // It will return an HTML page with a link to trigger the listMyFolders function.
  var html = "<html><body><a href='/listFolders'>Generate Folder List</a></body></html>";
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}

function listMyFolders() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear(); // Clear existing data (optional)
  sheet.appendRow(["Folder Name", "Owner Email", "Folder Link"]); // Headers

  function processFolder(folder) {
    var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      var subfolder = subfolders.next();
      var row = [
        subfolder.getName(),
        subfolder.getOwner().getEmail(),
        subfolder.getUrl()
      ];
      sheet.appendRow(row);
      processFolder(subfolder); // Recurse into subfolders
    }
  }

  processFolder(rootFolder);
}

Since Copilot gave me the code, I just asked them how to troubleshoot this. I basically tried:
1. Multiple Logged-In Accounts

logging out of all my google accounts and just logging in using the account i need to use to run the script
using incognito mode
using different browsers, and different browsers private mode

2. Check the Web App URL:

double checking that the url i copied from the manage deployment web app deployer thing is correct (I really have no idea if i did this right, but i just looked at the URL really closely each time i progressed to a new stage -- always failing at the HTML part.)

3. Permissions and Scopes

another thing idk if I'm checking correctly, but if its helpful i've made two deployments (both don't work); where one is "Execute as: Only me" and the other is "Execute as: User accessing the web app", both of them are set so that only those that are authorized to run it is anyone in my workspace.

4. Check for Script Errors

another possible issue, i of course don't know how to check for a script error. It runs perfectly fine when I run the script though, and if it helps I tried the debugging button, but nothing comes out. So this could be it?

5. Inspect Browser Console

i would not even know what to look for if i tried this, but it was telling me to press F12 and to look at the error message here. This is what it ended up looking like:
enter image description here

6. Recreate the Web App

did this, and the second spreadsheet i made gave me the same results. Basically, the script is working, but the web app is not.

7. Checking online solutions

ive seen users from years ago saying that they gave it a day or so and they were able open the file, while others mostly saying it was a multiple account issue, or even that it was a bug from google (now long resolved), but I've not encountered anything related to my situation where, I've tried incognito and logging out of my accounts and it still won't work. Or rather there are, but no one is answering.


Recursion can be difficult to grasp.

This works:
function listMyFolders() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var arr = [["Folder Name", "Owner Email", "Folder Id","Parent"],[fldr.getName(),fldr.getOwner().getEmail(),fldr.getId(),fldr.getParents().next().getName()]];
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("list",JSON.stringify(arr)); 
  processFolder(fldr);
  Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("list").replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
}
function processFolder(folder) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("list"));
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var sfldr = subfolders.next();
    arr.push([sfldr.getName(),sfldr.getOwner().getEmail(),sfldr.getId(),sfldr.getParents().next().getName()]);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("list",JSON.stringify(arr));
    processFolder(sfldr); 
  }
}

I just stored the folders in a 2d array using PropertiesService.
This is what my output looks like if you paste it into a spreadsheet by parsing the output and using setValues().  I have a side bar that has a textarea that grabs the JSON parses it and saves it into the active sheet.  And I have a tool that creates markup for pasting and redacting it into markup for posting on SO.




A
B
C
D




1
Folder Name
Owner Email
Folder Id
Parent


2
Media
Redacted
Redacted
My Drive


3
Notes
Redacted
Redacted
Media


4
National Geographic Mag
Redacted
Redacted
Media


5
Audio
Redacted
Redacted
Media


6
Google Earth KML files
Redacted
Redacted
Media


7
Videos
Redacted
Redacted
Media


8
Maps
Redacted
Redacted
Media


9
Music
Redacted
Redacted
Media


10
Images
Redacted
Redacted
Media


11
Thread on blanket
Redacted
Redacted
Images


12
Catheter images
Redacted
Redacted
Images


13
Poops
Redacted
Redacted
Images


14
Ani
Redacted
Redacted
Images


15
Parks
Redacted
Redacted
Images


16
Pipes
Redacted
Redacted
Images


17
Cetera
Redacted
Redacted
Images


18
inlineImages
Redacted
Redacted
Images


19
Dogs
Redacted
Redacted
Images


20
Health
Redacted
Redacted
Images


21
Learning Apps Script Images
Redacted
Redacted
Images


22
Vacination Card
Redacted
Redacted
Images


23
Phishing
Redacted
Redacted
Images


24
Spice Mix
Redacted
Redacted
Images


25
uploads
Redacted
Redacted
Images


26
Australia
Redacted
Redacted
Images


27
ECG
Redacted
Redacted
Images


28
FormImages
Redacted
Redacted
Images


29
TempImages
Redacted
Redacted
Images




Thank you Cooper! Just a question, am I supposed to set anything up before pasting your code? I get this error when I try to run it so I'm just wondering:
"Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."
Thank you!

I don't really know because I can't make it happen
